# Helm Chart to copy content to emptyDir

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm chart for deployment in openshift and I have different stages for deployment on different environment. I want to upload a .js file based on the container during the helm install/upgrade stage. The .js files are inside helm directory on same level as values.yaml.

```
my_project/
├── charts/
│   ├── my_app/
│   │   ├── templates/
│   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   ├── values.yaml
|   |   |-- jsfiles/
├── src/
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── utils/
│   │   └── helper.js
├── assets/
│   ├── images/
│   │   └── logo.png
├── index.html
```

my Idea is to create an emptyDir and use init Containers to copy file to the mounted volume which can then be used by the main container.However I am not able to provide reference to local file
I am using similar config as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "your-app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "your-app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: copy-codebase-filee
          image: alpine
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -R /jsfiles/* /emptydir"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: emptydir
              mountPath: /emptydir
      containers:
        - name: your-app
          image: your-image:tag
          volumeMounts:
            - name: emptydir
              mountPath: /app
      volumes:
        - name: emptydir
          emptyDir: {}
```

Also I tried the this config but the JS file is larger then 1Mb so cant use below config map.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jksconfig
data:
  config.json: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "config.json" | indent 4 }}
```

Comment: If the batch of files is over 1 MB, it seems like it's more than just configuration; what's actually there, and can it be "baked in" to the image?  Mounting the `emptyDir` volume over `/app` seems like it's likely to hide the contents of the image entirely, which you probably don't want.